# User-defined literal fails to include another file

Tags: c++, include, user-defined-literals, cxxtest

I have a class Komp where I have a user-defined literal `constexpr Komp operator""_i(long double x)` to produce a komp object from e.g `Komp k = 1 + 5.0_i;`.

This works fine in *komp.cpp*'s main(), however when I write the same exact statement in testing.cpp (where *komp.h* is included) I get the error below. Every other function in *komp.h* works fine in *testing.cpp*. I expected the user-defined literal to be included as the other functions are.

**Why is the user-defined literal not working in *testing.cpp* while other functions are?**

The error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator"" _i(long double)", referenced from:
      MyTestSuite::test5() in komp_testrunner-d3c20f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

```
// komp.cpp
class Komp {
    private:
        double val1;
        double val2;
    public: 
        // ... Bunch of member-function headers
        constexpr Komp(const double x, const double y) : val1(x), val2(y) {}
        double v1() {return val1;}
        double v2() {return val2;}
};
// ... Bunch of member and non-member functions.
Komp operator+ (const double lhs, const Komp rhs) { // overloads + operator for: double + Komp
    return Komp(lhs+rhs.v1(), rhs.v2());
}
constexpr Komp operator""_i(long double x) { // To match i.e Komp k = 1 + 2.3_i
    return Komp(0.0, x);
}
constexpr Komp operator""_i(unsigned long long x) { // To match i.e Komp k = 1 + 2_i
    return Komp(0.0, x*1.0);
}
int main() { // Only here temporarily for testing purposes
    Komp k = 1 + 2.0_i; // Works here
}
```

```
// komp.h
#include <string>
#ifndef KOMP_H
#define KOMP_H
class Komp
{
    public: 
        double val1;
        double val2;
        // ...
        Komp(const double x, const double y);
};
// ...
Komp operator+ (const double lhs, const Komp rhs);
Komp operator ""_i(long double arg);
Komp operator ""_i(unsigned long long arg);
#endif
```

```
#include "komp.h"
#include <cxxtest/TestSuite.h>

class Testing : public CxxTest::TestSuite {
  public:
    void literalTest () {
      Komp c = 3.0 + Komp(2.0, 2.0); // Works fine. No problem with overloading + operator
      Komp b = 5.0 + 2.0_i; // Causing an error
      Komp c = Komp(1.0, 2.0);
      TS_ASSERT(b != c); 
    }
};
```

Comment: How come your Komp class is defined in both cpp and .h file?

Comment: The code defines the class `Komp` in both the .h and the .cpp file. That's not the usual convention; it's legal, but the usual approach is for the .cpp file to `#include` the .h file. That would fix one problem in this code, that the two definitions of `Komp` are different.

Answer (score 1):

This function declaration:

```
Komp operator ""_i(long double arg);
```

is the only one visible to `testing.cpp`, or any file that includes `Komp.h`. However, you have not defined this function anywhere.

Note that this definition:

```
constexpr Komp operator""_i(long double x) { // To match i.e Komp k = 1 + 2.3_i
    return Komp(0.0, x);
}
```

is `constexpr`, so it's a different function. Simply declare the function as `constexpr` as well in `Komp.h`.

Also, you have defined the `Komp` class in `Komp.cpp`, as well as `Komp.h`. This is technically legal, but only if both the definitions are identical. In your case, the definitions are different, which violates the *one-definition-rule*, which means your program has undefined behavior. You should define `Komp` only in `Komp.h`.

Comment: Re: "if you change one definition, but not the other" -- in this case, that's already happened. The two definitions are not the same.

Comment: @PeteBecker True, I didn't even notice that; I assumed OP had copy-pasted the definition. Thanks for the correction, edited the answer.